# How does OpenGL know the input position (vertex shader)

Tags: opengl, shader

I am still kinda confused by the position input in the vertex shader. Because you never actually asign that variable. Does OpenGL just know it?

It's the same with sampler2d. You never assign that variable either, and in all of the tutorials I've seen/read that's never adressed.

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
uniform sample2d textureSampler.
```

Comment: Try reading this: https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Hello-Triangle

Comment: "You never assign that variable either" sure you do, what do you think your `glVertexAttribPointer()` calls do?

Comment: @genpfault Good point. I never linked that to the position though. So it's interpolating the positions of each pixel from the vertices?

Comment: @Amadeus thanks! beautiful tutorial.